# Python: Issue when trying to read and write multiple files

Tags: python, regex, iterator

This script reads and writes all the individual html files in a directory. The script reiterates, highlight and write the output.The issue is, after highlighting the last instance of the search item, the script removes all the remaining contents after the last search instance in the output of each file. Any help here is appreciated.

```
import os
import sys
import re

source = raw_input("Enter the source files path:")

listfiles = os.listdir(source)

for f in listfiles:
    filepath = os.path.join(source+'\\'+f)
    infile = open(filepath, 'r+')
    source_content = infile.read()

    color = ('red')
    regex = re.compile(r"(\b in \b)|(\b be \b)|(\b by \b)|(\b user \b)|(\bmay\b)|(\bmight\b)|(\bwill\b)|(\b's\b)|(\bdon't\b)|(\bdoesn't\b)|(\bwon't\b)|(\bsupport\b)|(\bcan't\b)|(\bkill\b)|(\betc\b)|(\b NA \b)|(\bfollow\b)|(\bhang\b)|(\bbelow\b)", re.I)

    i = 0; output = ""
    for m in regex.finditer(source_content):
        output += "".join([source_content[i:m.start()],
                           "<strong><span style='color:%s'>" % color[0:],
                           source_content[m.start():m.end()],
                           "</span></strong>"])

        i = m.end()
    outfile = open(filepath, 'w')
    outfile.seek(0, 2)
    outfile.write(output)
    print "\nProcess Completed!\n"
    infile.close()
    outfile.close()


raw_input()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your for loop is over, you need to include whatever is left after the last match:

```
        ...
        i = m.end()
    output += source_content[i:])  # Here's the end of your file
    outfile = open(filepath, 'w')
    ...
```

Comment: Yes, I missed that.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome.  If this solved your problem, consider marking this answer as "accepted" so future users can see that it worked for you.